# Is there a way to display a person's username by default on forms?

Tags: python, html, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Nothing i do seems to work out for me. I tired different models and forms but ultimately i get weird errors so all i can provide is the default code.

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Your Name"
        })
    )
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Leave a comment!"
        })
    )
```

views.py

```
def blogdetail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)

    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post,
            )
            comment.save()

    context = {"post": post, "comments": comments, "form": form}
    return render(request, "blogdetail.html", context)
```

blogdetail.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <small>
        {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
        Categories:&nbsp;
        {% for category in post.categories.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blogcategory' category.name %}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>&nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    </small>
    <p>{{ post.body | linebreaks }}</p>
    <h3>Leave a comment:</h3>
    <form action="/blog/{{ post.pk }}/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.author }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.body }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h3>Comments:</h3>
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <p>
        On {{comment.created_on.date }}&nbsp;
        <b>{{ comment.author }}</b> wrote:
    </p>
    <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

i want to relace author with the username of the user who wrote that comment. How so? what do i  need to change to make this happen?

Comment: Why do you use a `CharField` in the model and not a `ForeignKey`? Why not hide the `author` field and fill it in by the view, so without showing it in the form).

Comment: how do i do that? im new to django, sorry.